# Fast way to get details of all transactions in a block

Tags: json-rpc

I would like to extract all transactions in history. 
What I'm presently doing is calling `getrawtransaction` and than `decoderawtransaction` for each transaction in the block. This works, except that the extraction process takes forever.

Is there a faster way to do this?

Comment: you can try this one https://github.com/ragestack/blockchain-parser

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `getblock` with verbosity level 2. e.g.

```
getblock 0000000000000000000cedb96c93635edfb2755a3357e7febe5929fb6db1658d 2
```

This will return the block with all of the transactions already decoded.

---

Since you mentioned that you are doing `getrawtransaction` and then `decoderawtransaction`, `getrawtransaction` has another parameter to decode a transaction for you so you don't have to go to `decoderawtransaction`. You can do something like

```
getrawtransaction 0374d2bab7ce78429dc8660fb0100f260e1528dca4854ca7d761dd849211ff75 true
```

---

Lastly, most RPCs have a set of options with a description of what they do and an explanation of the output. You can do something lie

```
help getblock
```

to get the help description. In the future, you can do this for any command that you are using so that you can use it to its fullest potential.